# How does the minecraft main menu play a "movie"

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, video

I've been wondering for a while, and been doing a lot of research on the subject: how does the main menu in minecraft play a "video". As far as i can tell, it's not a .gif, it appears to be a movie. What is it that minecraft does that allows the moving background in the menu? Sorry for the lack of depth... but that's the question! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns trivia about how a particular game implemented a particular effect.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Are you trying to replicate the effect? If so, it doesn't matter how Minecraft did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a few chunks of a specifically seeded world viewed through a camera with a blur effect added that is slowly moving.  I believe there is a way to change it though that would be another question.

Comment: well, i know what the video is of, but i'm asking WHAT the video is, is it an MP3, gif, etc. and how is it being played? cause if it's an mp3/4, how would that run cause i've been trying to figure that out for ever

Comment: It likely not pre-rendered (it's not a "video" at all). It's just the game displaying a world the same way the game displays the world when you are playing, except with a runtime filter applied.

Comment: Indeed it is not a video just change your texture pack and you will see the background in the main menu changes to the texture pack.